# Any way to fail a build if package name is wrong using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

We have a CompilingClassloader that uses package names to find the source *.java files but someone recently modified the name to not match location, so it completely failed in a bizarre way.

Anyway we can have gradle fail the build when package name does not match java file location?

hmm, I guess according to mentallurg, this build was supposed to fail(which would rock)...instead it passed.  NOTE: I 'head -3' the file in question that has the wrong package name(you can read the file path to see how it is different).  I know javac allows that, but wondering if gradle matches eclipse which does not(that would be nice).

[image]

The version of gradle is 5.6.3

Comment: Java doesn't fail compilation if an arbitrary class file is found in an arbitrary folder, so Gradle couldn't realistically enforce that unless you wrote a custom task to do so.  I'm concerned about this approach though; this sounds like you need a **test** more than your build tool to care about where you're putting Java files as a part of your business logic.

Comment: yes, I know java doesn't, however eclipse enforces it pretty well and intellij at least shows red.  just looking for a gradle plugin or something.

Comment: @DeanHiller: It is not clear what you want. If your Gradle knows the project structure, and if package name does not correspond to file location, then compilation launched by Gradle will fail. That's why it is not clear what another fail you need.

Comment: @mentallurg so I uploaded a picture then of head -3 pathToFile showing a package not matching the file path (allowed in javac but not eclipse).  Was that build supposed to fail?

Comment: Googling for an existing solution came up empty. A simple gradle task wouldn't be that hard to write though. loop through all java files comparing path to package.

Comment: @DeanHiller: 1) Show the contents of your *build.gradle*. 2) Show the file list in the directory where you start Gradle (ls -al).

Comment: @DeanHiller: You cited me *incorrectly*. I wrote *If your Gradle knows the project structure...* Example: If you have folders with non-standard names and have not configured Gradle properly, Gradle doesn't know where your files are. That's why Gradle will have nothing to, and will report that it completed the build successfully. When Gradle *knows* your project structure, it will know what files are source files. If they are incorrect, build will fail. Since your build is successful, it means that very probably Gradle just ignored these files and *has not* compiled them.

Comment: well, the project is standardized.  I will have to test this issue more.........I have been jumping between very complex issues confusing me.  The build was only fast because I had run it just before so I would have less lines to cut/paste into SO.

Comment: and to be clear, gradle is compiling my files @mentallurg we have a complete CI chain working and have this in production.  I ended up adding a setting in webpieces compiler options called mustBeFromCompileClassLoader={package prefix} so any files with package prefix MUST be found on filesystem or it will fail.  gradle works fine but unfortunately builds with incorrect package not matching the name, but the DevServer at least catches it to not confuse developers with cryptic errors.  I wish I could fix grade, but oh well.